# C Array Segmentation Faults only after a certain threshold

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm looking at this simple program. My understanding is that trying to modify the values at memory addresses past the maximum index should result in a segmentation fault. However, the following code runs without any problems. I am even able to print out all 6 of the array indexes 0->6

```
main()
{
  int i;
  int a[3];

  for(i=0; i<6; i++)
        a[i] = i;

}
```

However, when I change the for loop to

```
for(i=0; i<7; i++)
```

and executing the program, it will segfault.
This almost seems to me like it is some kind of extra padding done by malloc. **Why does this happen only *after* the 6th index (s+6)? Will this behavior happen with longer/shorter arrays?** Excuse my foolishness as lowly java programmer :)

Comment: Which environment is this? For example - in MSVC Debug build there's a whole lot of padding done for each allocated block to detect memory access violations. In your particular case it could just be that the **minimal** amount of memory allocatable by system happens to be `sizeof(int)*6`

Comment: Whatever behavior you're seeing when accessing memory outside your array is undefined behavior/unreliable. It may very well crash on the next run or work reliably for years until that really bad time to crash.

Comment: Run your code through assembly and read what the compiler produced - that should provide you with some excellent insights into why is this working the way it does

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This almost seems to me like it is some kind of extra padding done by malloc.

You did not call malloc(). You declared `a` as an array of 3 integers in stack memory, whereas malloc() uses heap memory. In both cases, accessing any element past the last one (the third one, `a[2]`, in this case) is undefined behaviour. When it's done with heap memory, it usually causes a segmentation fault.

Comment: I seemed to think malloc() and declaring an array were the same. i dont know why. seems that i have a lot more reading ahead!

Answer (score 4):

Well, `malloc` didn't do it, because you didn't call `malloc`. My guess is, the extra three writes were enough to chew through your frame pointer and your stack pointer, but not through your return address (but the seventh one hit that). Your program is not guaranteed to crash when you access out-of-bounds memory (though there are other languages which do guarantee it), any more than it is guaranteed *not* to crash. That's what undefined behavior is: unpredictable.

Answer (score 3):

As others said, accessing an array beyond its limits is undefined behaviour. So what happens? If you access memory that you should not access, it depends on where that memory is.

Generally (but very generally, specifics can vary between systems and compilers), the following main things can happen:

- It can be that you simply access other variables of your process that lie directly "behind" the array. If you write to that memory, you simply modify the values of the other variables. You will probably not get a segfault, so you may never notice why your program produces bad results or acts so weird or why, during debugging, your variables have values you never (knowlingly) assigned to them. This is, IMO, really bad, because you think everything is fine while it isn't.
- It can be, especially on a stack, that you access other data on the stack, like saved processor registers or even the address to which the processor should return if the function ends. If you overwrite these with some other data, it is hard to tell what happens. In that case, a segfault is probably the lesser of all possible evils. You simply don't know what can happen.
- If the memory beyond your array does not belong to your process then, on most modern computers, you will get a segfault or similar exception (e.g. an access violation, or whatever your OS calls it).

I may have forgotten a few more possible problems that can occur, but those are, IMO, the most usual things that happen if you write beyond array bounds.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the free memory available, if free memory available is less then it will give segmentation fault otherwise it will use the extra memory to store the data and it will not be giving segmentation fault.There is no need for malloc because array itself allocates memory.

In your system memory is available only for 6 integers and when you are trying to access to next memory(which is not accessible or say not free)it is giving segmentation fault.

Comment: Free memory is usually taken from the heap. This is a stack problem. And there doesn't have to be a segmentation fault, if you access an array beyond its limits. A segfault is only one of the possible outcomes.

Comment: @AnujGarg - Judging from your answer history, you seem to be in a habit of providing answers with minimal explanation, or answers that are based on completely the wrong facts.  Please keep this in mind before you decide to answer your next question